# Sorting Result In ShinyApp

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

i have a shinyApp and i want to sort my correlation column (decreasing).
this is my app:https://abdalmoamen95.shinyapps.io/Correlation/

and this's my server code:

```
server <- function(input,output){
  output$Itemcorr <- renderTable({
    subset(DF, DF$FirstItem == input$Item)
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using the dplyr package.

```
library(dplyr)
server <- function(input,output){
  output$Itemcorr <- renderTable({
   DF %>% filter(FirstItem == input$Item) %>% arrange(desc(X.Correlation))
  })
}
```

Comment: Awesome, Thanks very much

Comment: can you help me in this question please ?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47619232/import-data-from-sql-server-to-shiny-app